# How do i fix this problem with my html href code?

Tags: html, href

So I am trying to make a website for some code homework I have but one of my html  link is not working. I've tried deleting the button function but it is still not working. I pasted the code from the other s and they seem to work. Only this won't work.

```
<nav>
<a href="Info.html"><button> INFO </button></a>
<a href="Ticket Purchase.html"><button> TICKET PURCHASE </button></a>
</nav>
```

The 'INFO' works, but the 'TICKET PURCHASE' one doesn't.

```
<nav>
<a href="Info.html"><button> INFO </button></a>
<a href="Ticket Purchase.html"> TICKET PURCHASE </a>
</nav>
```

I thought maybe my button was doing something so I removed it, but it still wouldn't work. I even pasted the name of the file into the space before ".html" part but it still won't work. I don't understand and to me, the code looks like it should work. I am using a local file thing because I do not need to post this online, so do not worry that that will affect the work.

I expected to be able to transport smoothly from one web page to the other, but this specific line of code does not work. I waited a long time, thinking it was just lag on my computer, but it just wouldn't work. Do note that changing the name of the local file or removing the space between them does not do anything.

Comment: Try removing the space in `Ticket Purchase`. Either change the filename of the html file to remove it, or change the link to `Ticket%20Purchase.html`

Comment: `<button>` elements are **forbidden** inside links.

Comment: I can't reproduce any problem when I test your code locally.

Comment: [not working](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) is a very unhelpful description of the problem. What happens when you try? Does the browser go to the wrong URL? Does nothing happen?

Comment: Sorry, I am not very familiar with being very specific. Anyways, not working is referring to the fact that the URL does absolutely nothing when clicked upon.

Comment: Here is my more complete version of my code, sorry I am making so many mistakes. ```<nav>
<a href="Info.html"><button> INFO </button></a>
<a href="TicketPurchase.html"><button> TICKET PURCHASE </button></a>
</nav>
<head>
<style>
body{background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSCsTGzzQRjs56uDDxvkZKc8prnc3wXTsSobC53y6g5uJo1YxXe2A")}
 </style>
<title> Alan Walker Malaysia Tour Home Page </title>
</head>```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the file name inside `href`. Thanks

**Example 1 - Change `Ticket Purchase.html` to `TicketPurchase.html`**

`<a href="TicketPurchase.html"> TICKET PURCHASE </a>`

**Example 2 - Change `Ticket Purchase.html` to `Ticket-Purchase.html`**

`<a href="Ticket-Purchase.html"> TICKET PURCHASE </a>`

Comment: Why? Spaces are allowed in URLs. They should be expressed as `%20` instead of a literal space, but I don't know of any browser that doesn't error recover that without a problem.

Comment: I tried, and it doesn't work... and not only that, the space is fine on my home page link. Here is the code: "<a href="Home Page.html"><button> HOME </button></a>" it works for this...

Comment: It'll be more clear if you share your complete code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Spaces are not allowed in URLs, that's why websites with long names are written together as a word. Putting space in a link will make a server convert the space to some special character. For this reason, files on your website should be named without spaces in between them.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the file from **"Ticket Purchase.html"** to **"ticketPurchase.html"**.

Comment: I am sorry, but thanks for the effort. This method does not work. I have tried it out, it does not work either.

Comment: then try - 
<button><a href ="filename">Name</a></button>

Comment: I've tried it, it still doesn't work. I really don't know what's causing this problem. I'm kind of frustrated right now...

Answer (score 0):

See docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/url-encoding

Some characters cannot be part of a URL (for example, the space).

So it should be:

```
<a href="TicketPurchase.html"> TICKET PURCHASE </a>
```

Comment: Do note that changing the name of the local file or removing the space between them does not do anything. I have done it, it still does not work.